# Gitlab Helmchart Disk Size Configuration

Tags: gitlab, kubernetes-helm

I am using the gitlab chart 5.2.3. In the values.yaml I have set the following:

```
gitlab:  
  gitaly:
    persistence:
      size: 500Gi
```

[image]

And when I check the System Info in Gitlab Admin I see the following information:
[image]

So, first it looks like that the storage max size is 50Gb and almost the whole storage is used up. I do not find the value in the values.yaml which has to be increased in order to allocate more space? Furthermore, why does the repository storage information does not appear here as well?

Comment: So what I found out in the meantime is that the size shown in screenshot is actually the node size of the kubernetes cluster and there will be issues if that limit is reached. So cluster nodes should have larger disk size.